# Java (Spring Boot) download file from FTP "Changing source IP is not permitted by Firebox policy"

Tags: java, docker, apache-commons

I'm trying to download a XML file using apache commons net 3.8.0 in Java Spring Boot.

```
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
        client.connect(url);
        boolean login = client.login(username, password);
        if (login) {
            System.out.println("Login success...");

            // Download file from FTP server.
            boolean status = client.retrieveFile(fileName, os);
            System.out.println("status = " + status);
            System.out.println("reply  = " + client.getReplyString());
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code works perfectly fine on my localhost. But when I deploy it, I get:
**"550 Permission denied. (Changing source IP is not permitted by Firebox policy)"**

The login seems to work just fine as it prints "Login success"

The deployed version is containerized using docker, the container is not exposed to public and is only reachable through a reverseproxy (caddy). The FTP server is not from me so I cannot change any settings there.
Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering the FTP using passiveMode was the trick